# cloudinary.openUploadWidget not working?

Tags: javascript, image, web-applications, widget, cloudinary

I am trying to use Cloudinary's API to allow users to upload a profile picture on an app I'm developing. I am using the 'cloudinary.openUploadWidget' in javascript.

So far, so good. However when I actually try and upload an image, I am getting the error: "Upload failed: Upload preset not found".

Any experience with this?

Here are the image upload settings: [Cloudinary Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iTy4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't set your upload preset. You can do this from your Cloudinary settings page and selecting "add upload preset".

Comment: Thanks for the input! BUT, I think we've already done that....on my Upload Preset page, we've enabled 'unsigned uploading'. Is there anything else in our settings page that we're potentially missing?

Comment: I've uploaded a snippet of what the settings look like, in my original question.